how to fix the connection to server undefined spring boot websocket/Angular
`i created a websocket using spring boot that sends notification to the users , i wanted than when i login as a user in angular i can receive my own notifications , the connection is established but i dont see any notifications + is shows connection to server undefined : Opening Web Socket...
compat-client.js:32 Web Socket Opened...
compat-client.js:32 >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.2,1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000
compat-client.js:32 Received data
compat-client.js:32 <<< CONNECTED
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.2
content-length:0
compat-client.js:32 connected to server undefined
test.component.ts:48 Connected to WebSocket server: FrameImpl {command: 'CONNECTED', headers: {…}, _binaryBody: Uint8Array(0), isBinaryBody: true, escapeHeaderValues: false, …}
websocket.service.ts:35 >>> SUBSCRIBE
ack:auto
id:sub-0
destination:/user/amal/queue/notification/item
@Configuration @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker @CrossOrigin(origins ="*") public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
public void dispatch() {
    List<User> listeners = userService.findAllUsers();
    for (User listener : listeners) {
        List<Notification> notifications = notificationService.getNotifUser(listener.getUser_id());

        System.out.println("Notifications for user " + listener.getUsername() + ": " + notifications);

        for (Notification notification : notifications) {
            if (!notification.isSent()) { 
                
                messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
                        listener.getUsername(),
                        "/queue/notification/item", 
                        notification
                );
                //notification.setSent(true); 
                //notificationService.updateNotification(notification); 
            }
        }
    }
}}

export class TestComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy { private notificationsSubscription!: Subscription; notifications: any[] = []; private username!: string;
constructor(
    private webSocketService: WebSocketService,
    private authService: AuthService 
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.authService.getCurrentUsername().subscribe((username: string | null) => {
        if (username) {
            this.username = username;
            this.connectAndSubscribeToNotifications();
        } else {
            console.error('Username is null, cannot subscribe to notifications');
        }
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.notificationsSubscription) {
        this.notificationsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.webSocketService.disconnect();
}

private connectAndSubscribeToNotifications(): void {
    this.webSocketService.connect().subscribe({
        next: (frame: any) => {
            console.log('Connected to WebSocket server:', frame);
            this.subscribeToNotifications();
        },
        error: (error: any) => {
            console.error('Error connecting to WebSocket server:', error);
        }
    });
}

private subscribeToNotifications(): void {

    const topic = `/user/${this.username}/queue/notification/item`;
    this.notificationsSubscription = this.webSocketService.subscribe(topic).subscribe({
        next: (notification: any) => {
            console.log('Received notification:', notification);
            this.notifications.push(notification); 
        },
        error: (error: any) => {
            console.error('Error subscribing to notifications:', error);
        }
    });
}

}
